# When submit the form, if the checkbox isn't checked, shows the tips and prevent the form submitted

Tags: jquery

the code:

```
<form>
<div class="term"><input type="checkbox" />I agree to the terms of the privacy </div>
<div id="tip"> please agree the terms of the privacy </div>
</form>
```

the jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#tip").hide();
          jQuery("form").submit(function() {

          if (jQuery('.term').is(':checked')) {
            jQuery("#tip").hide();

          }
          else {
          jQuery("#tip").show();
           return false;
    } 
        });
        });
```

when i checked the checkbox, then submit the form, the tips still shows. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector for "term" is a div, not a checkbox. The checkbox is a child of "term"

```
   if( jQuery('.term input:checkbox').is(':checked') ){
```

Answer (score 0):

define term class on your checkbox field as

```
        <div class="test"><input type="checkbox" class="term" />I agree to the terms of the privacy </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you've shown is that your checkbox doesn't have the class "term" that your jQuery selector uses. The div that it is in has the class "term". So you need to either change the input to be like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="term" />
```

Or change the jQuery selector to be like this:

```
if (jQuery('.term input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
```

Having said that, given that there is exactly one of these checkboxes I'd be inclined to give it an id and select by id.